# SQL UPDATE with error

Tags: sql, sql-update

I would appreciate any help with my code, I keep getting an error

> SQL command not properly ended' from Toad.

```
UPDATE GS_MRC_EXISTING  GME
SET GME.GROSS_LAST = STC.SALES 
WITH STC AS 
( 
SELECT DISTINCT ( DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY ) AS CUSTS, 
           SUM ( CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE >=0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS SALES,
           SUM ( CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE <=0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS DISCOUNT
FROM    DAILY_SALES_FACT  DSF,
            MATERIAL_DIM MD    
WHERE 
DSF.SALES_DOC_TYPE_SID = '10'  
AND DSF.MATERIAL_SID = MD.MATERIAL_SID  
AND DSF.NET_PRICE <> 0
AND DSF.TPNM_ACTUAL_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160731'   
GROUP BY DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY
)
WHERE GME.CUST_CODE = STC.CUSTS;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Toad suggests Oracle.  And that suggests subqueries for such an `update` (or `merge`):

```
UPDATE GS_MRC_EXISTING GME
    SET GME.GROSS_LAST = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE >= 0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS SALES
                          FROM DAILY_SALES_FACT DSF JOIN
                               MATERIAL_DIM MD  
                               ON DSF.MATERIAL_SID = MD.MATERIAL_SID  
                          WHERE DSF.SALES_DOC_TYPE_SID = '10' AND
                                DSF.NET_PRICE <> 0 AND
                                DSF.TPNM_ACTUAL_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160731' AND
                                DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY = GME.CUST_CODE
                         );
```

Note:  This updates all rows, even those that don't match.  You may want to restrict this:

```
UPDATE GS_MRC_EXISTING GME
    SET GME.GROSS_LAST = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE >= 0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS SALES
                          FROM DAILY_SALES_FACT DSF JOIN
                               MATERIAL_DIM MD  
                               ON DSF.MATERIAL_SID = MD.MATERIAL_SID  
                          WHERE DSF.SALES_DOC_TYPE_SID = '10' AND
                                DSF.NET_PRICE <> 0 AND
                                DSF.TPNM_ACTUAL_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160731' AND
                                DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY = GME.CUST_CODE
                         )
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM DAILY_SALES_FACT DSF JOIN
                   MATERIAL_DIM MD  
                   ON DSF.MATERIAL_SID = MD.MATERIAL_SID  
              WHERE DSF.SALES_DOC_TYPE_SID = '10' AND
                    DSF.NET_PRICE <> 0 AND
                    DSF.TPNM_ACTUAL_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160731' AND
                    DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY = GME.CUST_CODE
             );
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, I will give that a go. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove "UPDATE" command after "WITH" section. And if you group result by field, you may not use "distinct" on that field. Like this:

```
WITH STC AS
(
    SELECT DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY AS CUSTS,
      SUM ( CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE >=0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS SALES,
      SUM ( CASE WHEN DSF.NET_PRICE <=0 THEN NET_PRICE ELSE 0 END  ) AS DISCOUNT
    FROM    DAILY_SALES_FACT  DSF,
      MATERIAL_DIM MD
    WHERE
      DSF.SALES_DOC_TYPE_SID = '10'
      AND DSF.MATERIAL_SID = MD.MATERIAL_SID
      AND DSF.NET_PRICE <> 0
      AND DSF.TPNM_ACTUAL_START_DATE_KEY BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160731'
    GROUP BY DSF.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_KEY
)
UPDATE GS_MRC_EXISTING SET GROSS_LAST = STC.SALES WHERE CUST_CODE = STC.CUSTS;
```

Comment: When I do that it wants a SELECT statement ?

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I flipped it around a bit to get it to work... UPDATE table x
SET x.field = (SELECT q.field
                             FROM query q
                              WHERE q.f2 = x.f2) – correlate this to get single row back
WHERE x.f3= value – restrict no of rows to update
;